# Подсветка синтаксиса C#

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-так-задумано

Вот такой кусок кода на C# в некоторых случаях вызывает неправильную подсветку синтаксиса:

```
string quote = @"\"";
int x = 0;
```

Это если у вопроса указан тег [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) или явно указан язык `<!-- language: c# -->`

Однако, именно здесь всё работает нормально даже в этом случае.

При помощи Grundy было обнаружено следующее: если язык явно задать таким образом: `<!-- language: lang-c# -->` то подсветка корректно работает всегда.

Возможно, стоит изменить выбор типа подсветки для [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) по умолчанию на второй вариант. Чтобы всегда работало.

Пример рабочей и нерабочей подсветки можно увидеть в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605960) сообщении.

Скриншот оттуда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, скриншоты с разным форматированием, для понимания того как правильно, а как нет.

Comment: либо еще один вариант: не был найден `lang-c#` и было применено какое-то форматирование по умолчанию, например как сейчас не указано ничего, но форматирование совпадает

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Пример без явного указания языка подсвечен *полностью корректно*:

```cs
string quote = @"\"";
int x = 0;
```

`int x = 0;` является частью строкового литерала. Смотрите как это выглядит в студии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему подсветка работает корректно без указания языка, но сбивается при явном указании языка `lang-c#`?

[На SO используется внешняя подсветка синтаксиса - Google Code Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/248633). Язык (`<!-- langauge: lang-zzz -->`) задает имя файла-расширения для GCP. Для C# это `lang-cs`.

`lang-cs` задан языком подсветки по умолчанию для тега [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). Если на вопросе установлен тег [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) - то код в вопросе и в ответах будет подсвечен с использованием `lang-cs`.

---

`lang-cs` поддерживает verbatim strings (начинающиеся с `@`). В verbatim strings не работает escaping через `\`, а кавычки эскейпятся как через `""`. И он разбирает ваш пример правильно (но не так, как вы ожидаете).

Языка `lang-c#` в GCP нет. Несуществующий `lang-c#` приводит к некорректной подсветке, с использованием `lang-default`. Которая хоть и выглядит нормально, но при этом некорректна.

Следующая подсветка, указанием `lang-c#`, **неправильна**:

```c#
string quote = @"\"";
int x = 0;
```

... точно так же неправильна подсветка с любого другого несуществующего языка, например `lang-nesisharp`:

```nesisharp
string quote = @"\"";
int x = 0;
```

Comment: Предлагаю хоты бы добавить подсказку о том, если синтаксис некорректно подсвечивается, то можете указать язык явно и ссылка на этот ответ на мете. Если бы не увидел случайно этот вопрос, то иначе бы не узнал.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov так суть моего ответа - язык уже указан *явно*, как lang-cs. проблема в том, что именно явное указание языка *иногда* вызывает некорректную подсветку.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что если ничего не указывать, а просто давать пример кода, то могут возникать проблемы с подсветкой, поэтому предлагаю добавить подсказку, так как не все знают, что язык можно явно указать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov так не должно быть проблем с подсветкой. вот в том вопросе, на который ссылается топикастер - если язык не указать - то проблем с подсветкой нет :)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov черт, все-таки есть :(

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov внезапно, обнаружил что этот пример - невалидный код на C#

Comment: тут дело не в языке, я тут 100% подобное на JavaScript находил. Поэтому предлагаю подсказку об этой возможности.

Comment: @PashaPash, так может проблема как раз в невалидном коде??? и да, сейчас попробовал - все нормально стало показываться :-D

Comment: @Grundy да, обновил ответ. ну и соответственно, ответ на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605958/ - совсем мимо.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov подсказку стоит оформить отдельным постом, лучше в виде перевода с английской меты.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov не вижу чем пост по ссылке противоречит моему ответу. наоборот, он полностью его подтверждает - нужно использовать lang-cs или не указывать язык (т..к lang-cs выставлен по умолчанию для [tag:c#]). lang-c# выдает default подсветку которая "working just fine", но вот в данном конкретном случае - неверна. Можете ткнуть пальцем в конкретную "неверность", пожалуйста?

Comment: Цитата: "*Языка lang-c# в GCP нет. Несуществующий lang-c# приводит к некорректной подсветке, с использованием lang-default. Которая хоть и выглядит нормально, но при этом некорректна.*" `c#` и `lang-cs` обязано работать идентично, как указано по ссылке.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov по ссылке это не указано. если указано - процитируйте плз :) более того, легко проверить что это не так - собственно, вот этот вопрос и возник из-за того, что lang-cs и lang-c# давали разную подсветку, и Alexander Petrov это обнаружил, но неправильно оценил, какая из них правильная.

Comment: @PashaPash Да, вы правы. Это я не различил `lang-c#` с `c#`. Хорошо, а сможете указать в ответе, что также можно просто `c#` и всевозможные синонимы `c-sharp`, `c#.net`, `c#-language`, `visual-c#`, `csharp` и `.cs-file`?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov синонимы заменяются на [tag:c#] самим движком. Подсветка задается в свойствах метки [tag:c#] вручную, модераторами, а не выводится из названия метки автоматом. Т.е. там есть комбик, где для C# выбран lang-cs.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov переформулировал ответ чуть-чуть