# Ошибка в справке по языку С# для подсветки

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, справка

Был задан [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4253/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-c) и получен [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4254/220571). Из ответа видно, что для подсветки синтаксиса используется Google Code Prettify и для C# подходит только `lang-cs`. Точнее это описано [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), но не суть.

Так вот: в [справке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), похоже, допущена ошибка на строчке `<!-- language: c# -->`. Здесь должно быть написано `<!-- language: lang-cs -->`.

Comment: Справка перекочевала с [англоязычного варианта](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Поэтому и править надо глобально.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, с чего вдруг такой статус?

Comment: @Nicolas Вроде у PashaPash и Qwertiy удалось найти баг в языковой подсветке, это рано отмечать "так-задумано".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось, [метки в роле зыка не работают](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609931/178988), так что в справке действительно ошибка.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Отлично, будете поднимать данный вопрос на мете? Я не уверен, что смогу хорошо это описать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а может, на этой дополним вопрос и допишем перевод?

Comment: Да можно, я разрешаю вам редактировать вопрос в любую сторону. Я что-то не чувствую, что смогу убедительно рассказать об ошибке в справке.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, лучше сам отредактируй, а я на английский переведу.

Comment: Хорошо, завтра сделаю.

Comment: здесь не редактировать а просто задавать другой вопрос надо потому что выяснилось, что всё совсем по другому. Адекватно объяснить почему "имена тегов в language писать нельзя" я не смогу, поэтому если хотите задайте этот вопрос на английской мете.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, в каком смысле "почему"? Просто не работает и всё же, не?

Comment: Тут нужны примеры, аргументация и т.д. Просто не работает так не пойдёт, сами знаете.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, скриншот же, нет?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51061/discussion-between-vadim-ovchinnikov-and-qwertiy).

Comment: `метки в роле зыка` – что вы имели в виду?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в соседнем ответе написано, что вместо указания языка `lang-cs` можно использовать любую метку, для которой этот язык выставлен: `c#`. Но это не работает, а в справке всё-таки ошибка.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Это не баг, как оказалось, а [так задумано](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287412/1548895). Больше информации вы найдёте [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/346987).</strike>

Суть в том что вы можете не только писать `<!-- language: lang-cs -->`, а также можно писать имена тэгов вместе с синонимами, к примеру для тэга [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23):
сам тэг `<!-- language: C# -->`,
и его синонимы `<!-- language: csharp -->`, `<!-- language: c#.net -->`, `<!-- language: c#-language -->`, `<!-- language: visual-c# -->`, `<!-- language: csharp -->` и `<!-- language: .cs-file -->`.

---

**Важно:** `language` и тэги (+ синонимы) будут работать только если в ответе используется этот тэг. В справке тоже всё верно указано, это я не так понял, хотя можно было бы указать что тэг именно вопроса.

---

Полагаю что в справке ошибка, и ошибку следует дальше исследовать. Смотрите [комментарий @PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4358/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%a1-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8#comment14817_4368) и [ответ @Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4377/220571).

Comment: имена тегов в `language` писать нельзя!  если на вопросе стоит тэг [tag:c#] то на весь код уже действует `lang-cs`. Вписывание `<!-- language: C# -->` при этом во первых бессмысленно (уже работает правильная подсветка, зачем что-то еще дописывать!), во вторых - вредно, т.к. `<!-- language: C# -->` **отключает** подсветку на основе тэга и включает кривую подсветку `default`

Comment: @PashaPash Тогда вам на главную мету. Требовать править [справку](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) и ответы: [раз](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) и [два](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287409/typo-in-markdown-help/287412#287412).

Comment: "только если в ответе используется этот тэг" - эм.. в ответе тег - это как? или в вопросе?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну в вопросе разумеется. В ответе тэгов не бывает. Поэтому, как я понимаю, в ответе надо использовать только коды Google Code Prettifier, если определённого тэга нет в вопросе.

Comment: Что-то действительно не работает: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609930/178988. Хотя именно вариант с `<!-- language: c# -->` сработал как надо. // cc @PashaPash

Comment: @Qwertiy он стработал из-за отсутствия префикса lang - `<!-- language: qqq -->` точно так же "работает". похоже, без префикса `lang-` директива игнорируется и используется язык вопроса (C#). с префиксом `lang-` срабатывает default.

Comment: @PashaPash, в таком случае в справке всё-таки ошибка.

Comment: @PashaPash А сможете поднять этот вопрос на английской мете из-за ошибок в справке и приведенных мною ответах?