# Не работает подсветка синтаксиса, когда явно задан язык после ```

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, подсветка-синтаксиса

Я заметил, что на сайте не работает подсветка синтаксиса, когда явно указан язык программирования после знаков ```. Например, ```c#. При этом указана метка языка.

Код для теста.

С четырьмя отступами:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

Заключённый в знаки ``` без указания языка:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

Заключённый в знаки ```c# с указанием языка:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

Причём, что любопытно, в режиме редактирования подсветка работает.

Comment: возможно неправильно указан язык, и вместо c# нужно csharp например

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Ошибка в справке по языку С# для подсветки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4358/176217)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вместо `c#` надо указывать `csharp` или `cs`. Примеры:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

````
```csharp
````

---

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

````
```cs
````

Comment: А как бы это теперь донести до тех, кто пишет ```c#?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не знаю. С модераторами посоветуйтесь.